Does a Windows MSI/installer function to a portable file in the PE format?
I'm trying to determine whether a Windows MSI or installer .exe is considered the same as a portable file .exe in the Portable Executable (PE) format, or if it's considered a dropper. What are the differences between them?

An MSI file is not a Portable Executable.  It's a database of information that describes how an application is installed or uninstalled.  It specifies which files go where, which registry settings are necessary, etc.  The application files, including executables and DLLs (which are PE files), may be wrapped in CAB files which are stored in the MSI.
The Windows Installer (msiexec.exe) is a program that ships with Windows and is responsible for "interpreting" an MSI when a user wants to install or uninstall an application.
Some applications use MSI installers, but there are other methods of writing an installer for Windows, including writing a program (a PE file) that does the work.  If you have an installer.exe or setup.exe, that is a Portable Executable file.
I'm not familiar with the term "dropper" in this context, so I'm not sure how to answer that part of the question.

A CAB file is a compressed archive of files, like a ZIP file.  CAB is short for cabinet.  An MSI database can contain one or more CAB files as blobs of binary data.
"Interpreting" in quotes because MSI is not interpreted in the sense that Javascript or Python is interpreted.  The MSI file is not a script.

By "dropper", he probably means an executable file that contains the installation files as raw resource data inside it and extracts them into a temp directory.
